# Oracle PL/SQL nested table processing comparison

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am working with Oracle 11gR2 PL/SQL tables (nested table), but just getting a little confused on whether the following two approaches are achieving the same result, i.e.:

Assuming I have defined the following TYPE:

```
type member_nos_type is table of varchar2(32000);
```

and the following sample table definition/data:

```
table: my_members

id        number not null,
membernos varchar2(30) not null,
first_nm  varchar2(255),
surname   varchar2(255)

Sample data in table my_members:

1  111111  Joe   Smith
2  222222  Sam   Smith
3  333333  Jane  Smith
4  444444  Jason Smith
5  555555  Joel  Smith
```

then within a procedure, I have the following code:

```
    procedure a1 (p_param1 in varchar2) is

      v_member_list        member_nos_type;

    begin
      if p_param1 = 'BASKETBALL' then
        v_member_list := member_nos_type ('222222','444444');
      end if;
    end;    
----------------------------    
    procedure b2 (p_param1 in varchar2) is

      v_member_list        member_nos_type;

    begin
      if p_param1 = 'BASKETBALL' then
        v_member_list := member_nos_type (
          SELECT LISTAGG(membernos, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY membernos)
          FROM my_members
          WHERE id in (2,4));
      end if;
    end;
```

Based on `procedure a1` and `procedure b2` above, is the end result a table of member numbers of type varchar2 ?

### Update

How can I return a TRUE nested table based on my membernos column data in my my_members table?

Comment: Did you not run it?  LISTAGG returns varchar2 - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Comment: Procedure `a1` makes true nested table type, while second procedure uses LISTAGG which returns one string, just values are separated by comma.

Comment: Ok, as what I suspected. Could someone pls let assist on how I would go about returning a true nested table, like I was attempting to with the LISTAGG function based on my membernos column data in my my_members table?

Comment: Please show some sample expected output, because not clear what you are attempting to do.  What exactly is "nested" here?  I don't see anything hierarchical.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if in that way you could populate a nested table. You can do it as below;

```
procedure b2 (p_param1 in varchar2) is

      v_member_list        member_nos_type;

    begin
      if p_param1 = 'BASKETBALL' then
      for rec in (Select membernos
                  from my_members
                  WHERE id in (2,4))
      loop
       v_member_list.extend();     
       v_member_list(rec):= rec.membernos;    

      End loop;   
      end if;

      For i in 1..v_member_list.count
      loop

       dbms_output.put_line(v_member_list(i));

      end loop;

    end;
```

PS: Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to

```
select cast(collect(membernos) as member_nos_type)
into v_member_list 
FROM my_members
WHERE id in (2,4);
```

I wouldn't really call it a nested table unless it is actually stored as a collection type in the database (which I don't recommend).